# cannot load such file -- mysql2/2.4/mysql2 (LoadError) - windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, mysql2

I am new on Ruby on Rails. My Ruby version is ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x64-mingw32].

I have created a new project using `rails new sample_cms -d mysql` command.

The command `rails server` is throwing following error.

```
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.6-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in `require': cannot load such file -- mysql2/2.4/mysql2 (LoadError)
```

I have installed mysql and mysql Connector C. I have installed the mysql2 gem like that.

```
gem install mysql2 —platform=ruby — ‘—with-mysql-dir="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1"’
```

I have uninstall and install the mysql2 gem but still facing the issue. 
Here is the directory which may have issue.

[image of directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0b6i.png)

Here is the gem file entry for mysql2

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.1'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.3.18', '< 0.5'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
```

Any Help?

Comment: As this is windows are you sure the folder security/user settings are OK and that ruby can access the files. Do you have any other gems which don't work or just `mysql2`

Comment: @user3788685. Yes... security is ok and also ruby can access the files.  Only mysql2 is not working :(

Comment: Also just spotted; in your `dir` pic there is no 2.4 but your path above shows its looking at `mysql2/2.4/mysql2`

Comment: Yes.. that is the issue. It seems that mysql2 for ruby2.4 is not available yet...

Comment: @user3788685. Can I downgrade the ruby version to 2.3 somehow? Or I need to install it from start?

Comment: What's the path of that screen shot? Have you tried copying the files to that path to see if it works? How did you install ruby? On Linux I'd say 'yes' but Windows is an unknown to me... sorry

Comment: @user3788685. Thank you... I have installed it through exe. I will find out.. I think ruby has change the way to install dev tools for 2.4. So i think i need to install it again. Will try also by copying

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no mysql2 binary for Ruby 2.4 for Windows available at this time. So i uninstall ruby 2.4 and install ruby 2.3. Now it is working well