# How to connect mysql2 to Ruby on Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, windows

I am trying to work on a RoR project, I have created the project called tester to check my db connection, command which I had used is 'rails new tester -d mysql'
my gemfile has mysql2 gem included
I have installed mysql and workbench, and my database.yml looks like this:

```
default: &default   
adapter: mysql2   
encoding: utf8
pool: <%=ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
username: root   
password: password
host: localhost   
socket: MySQL

development:   <<: *default   
database: tester_development

test:   <<:*default
database: tester_test 

production:   <<: *default   
database: tester_production
username: tester   
password: <%=ENV['TESTER_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

And my cmd error is following:

```
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.9-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in `require': cannot load such file -- mysql2/2.4/mysql2 (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.9-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.9-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.9-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
        from C:/Users/donki/Desktop/testing/tester/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:133:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:133:in `block in perform'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `perform'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Sorry for the long post. I really do not understand what the error is. The error occurs when I try to run rails server.
Help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am not allowed to add pictures to the posts yet

Answer (score 1):

It's seems like you are using windows and ruby 2.4

but I think mysql2 library not support ruby 2.4 in windows till now,

So, It would be better to use ruby 2.3 instead of ruby2.4

Hope it will help you.

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44732205/cannot-load-such-file-mysql2-2-4-mysql2-loaderror-windows)

Comment: I am using the latest versions of Ruby and Rails, if it happens that it doesn't work, i will the have to stick to default sqlite3, and windows as OS right

Comment: if you don't want to downgrade ruby then sqlite3 will work for you.