# cannot load such file -- mysql2/2.4/mysql2 (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby On Rails. I have been trying to create a model called Book using ***rails generate model Book*** command but I am getting the following error message:

```
F:\Faizul\Noah-Data\Backup\Ruby\Rails App\library>rails generate model Book
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.10-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in `require': cannot load such file -- mysql2/2.4/mysql2 (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.10-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.10-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.10-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
        from F:/Faizul/Noah-Data/Backup/Ruby/Rails App/library/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:15:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:15:in `require_application_and_environment!'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/generate/generate_command.rb:19:in `perform'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Made the below actions to overcome the issue but failed though :(

- Uninstalled mysql2
- Installed mysql2 using **gem install mysql2 command**
- Added 'msql2' to my Gemfile
- Configured **database.yml** file as below:

> ```
> default: &default
>   adapter: mysql2
>   pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
>   timeout: 5000
>
> development:
>    adapter: mysql2
>    database: library_development
>    username: root
>    password: root
>    host: localhost
>    port: 3309
> test:
>    adapter: mysql2
>    database: library_test
>    username: root
>    password: root
>    host: localhost
>    port: 3309
> production:
>    adapter: mysql2
>    database: library_production
>    username: root
>    password: root
>    host: localhost
>    port: 3309
> ```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44742417/297087

Comment: have you run `bundle install`?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, There is no mysql2 binary for Ruby 2.4 for Windows available at this time.

Please see [this](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/861) github issue for more info
https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/861

Hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

compile your mysql comment worked for me
https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/923#issuecomment-361346864

**but be aware that at step #3**
instead of

> cd  "C:\Ruby24-x64\bin\ruby" extconf.rb --with-mysql-dir="C:\Program
>   Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector.C 6.1"

I did

> "C:\Ruby24-x64\bin\ruby" extconf.rb --with-mysql-dir="C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector.C 6.1"

no "cd" at the begging and my connector was in "C:\Program Files (x86)" folder.

**also at step #6**
I was copying

> C:\Ruby24-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.4.0\gems\mysql2-0.4.10-x64-mingw32\ext\mysql2\mysql2.so

to newly created folder

> C:\Ruby24-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.4.0\gems\mysql2-0.4.10-x64-mingw32\lib\mysql2\2.4

compiling process was showing plenty warnings but eventually rake db:migrate started work for me, so should yours code

Answer (score 0):

Please install Mysql server .
Install below gems.

Libmysqlclient-dev 
Or 
Mysql-devl