# Rails 5.2 Server Error - Complete Newbie

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been trying to get rails environment up and running.  I installed rails 5.2.0 as well as ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x64-mingw32] initially on Win 7 along with XAMPP.  I created a new demo app as well as ported an existing app over. After launching the server and mysql,  I would try to launch rails server and kept getting errors.  I noticed numerous updates needed in Win 7 and kept doing those and retrying, but kept getting the same errors.  Eventually, I bit the bullet and upgraded to Win10 after someone indicated it was an OS issue and Win8/10 alot better for this.  Unfortunately, I still get the same error.

Can someone please give me some guidance as to how to move forward?  thks

This error results from trying to launch the server for a virgin newly created demo app. I have not modified any files at all.

```
C:\demo>rails s
Traceback (most recent call last):
        43: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
        42: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `require'
        41: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
        40: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `block in require'
        39: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
        38: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        37: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
        36: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        35: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
        34: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        33: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
        32: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
        31: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
        30: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        29: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        28: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
        27: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
        26: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:145:in `block in perform'
        25: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `require'
        24: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
        23: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `block in require'
        22: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
        21: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        20: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
        19: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        18: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
        17: from C:/demo/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        16: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
        15: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
        14: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
        13: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
        12: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
        11: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        10: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
         9: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
         8: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
         7: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
         6: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
         5: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
         4: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
         3: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `require'
         2: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
         1: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `block in require'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your `Rails` app uses `sqlite` database, when you're expecting it to use `MySQL`. You need to reconfigure it then:

Change your `config/database.yml` to something like:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: your_app_name_dev
  username: user
  password:
  host: localhost
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

And include `mysql2` gem into your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

Comment: I updated both the gem file and the database.yml but still same errors.  Here is the gemfile.

Comment: and have you removed sqlite3 gem from Gemfile?

Comment: just removed sqlite3 gem, now giving error:  Failed to load libmysql.dll from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.2-x64-mingw32/vendor/libmysql.dll

Comment: then try to specify `gem 'mysql2', '0.3.21'` instead of `gem 'mysql2'` and run `bundle update mysql2`

Comment: actually, new error is slightly different and is referencing mysql2 (whereas initially it was referencing sqlite3.   C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require': cannot load such file -- mysql2/2.5/mysql2 (LoadError)

Comment: according to this answer, to use mysql you probably need to uninstall ruby 2.5 and install 2.3 https://stackoverflow.com/a/44742417/2199600

Comment: Success for now.  I did end up removing 2.5 and install 2.3.3 with webkit and rails 5.2.0.  I created a new demo app using sqlite db, launched the server and success.  I am now going to move on to try to get the mysql db approach working.  Thanks for help!!

Comment: you're welcome. feel free to accept the answer (tick near the answer) if you think the question is answered

Comment: Getting closer:  For testing the mysql connection, i created another demo app,  modified the gem file to reference mysql 0.3.21, and in the database yml, I have the reference to adapter: mysql in development. (I still have adapter: sqlite3 in default section,  should this be changed?)  I am getting error: Error loading the 'mysql2' Active Record adapter. Missing a gem it depends on? can't activate mysql2 (< 0.6.0, >= 0.4.4), already activated mysql2-0.3.21-x64-mingw32. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile in browser now.

Comment: That last error is in browser.  Server launches successfully,  error seems to  be for the db connection.

Comment: More success...amazingly.  I ended up adding gem 'activerecord-mysql2-adapter' into the gem file.   From there, I was getting a credentials error.  I checked phpmyadmin directly and created the db directly.  I also noted that it was giving the user name as 'root', not 'user', so I edited the database.yml to use 'root'.  After that,  I launched server again..and voila...got the main welcome page.